# IronPython: script validation via C# code

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I'm working with IronPython in a C#/.Net Core 3.1 project and I need to be able to validate a script before executing it in a production environment.

I have found [this solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32cc8680-83d7-483e-a8fe-8e427c5134bb/how-to-use-microsoftscriptinghostingerrorlistener?forum=csharpgeneral), creating my custom `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ErrorListener` implementation:

```
public class IronPythonListener : ErrorListener
{
    public List<ValidationError> Errors = new List<ValidationError>();

    public override void ErrorReported(ScriptSource source, string message, SourceSpan span, int errorCode, Severity severity)
    {
        Errors.Add(new ValidationError
        {
            Message = message,
            ErrorCode = errorCode,
            Severity = severity,
            Span = span
        });
    }
}
```

and then passing an instance of it to the `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Compile(ErrorListener)` method:

```
IronPythonListener listener = new IronPythonListener();
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource scriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script, SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);
CompiledCode code =  scriptSource.Compile(listener);
```

In `listener.Errors` list I find all the compilation errors.

This solution works, but for my purposes it is not complete, because for example:

- if the passed script is something like `my_var = 5 + "some text"`, `listener.Errors` is empty and the script is considered valid even though it cannot be executed (in fact, it throws a `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` exception)
- if the passed script contains calls to undefined functions (e.g. `length(my_string)` instead of `len(my_string)`), it is considered valid

Another thing that seems strange to me is that all the errors I can find are of type `Severity.FatalError` (e.g. passing `my_var = 6 +`), but I'm not able to find any `Severity.Error` or `Severity.Warning`.

Is there a way to improve the validation, without executing my compiled script?

Thanks in advance for any help, unfortunately I cannot find so much documentation about this.

**Edit**: I found some online validators (e.g. https://repl.it/languages/python3 or http://pep8online.com/) and they also don't provide a complete python validation (in the former one, validation is handled better by the IDE, but the `5 + "some text"` error is detected only at execution time). Of course I can try to execute the script and catch the exception when `listener.Errors` is empty, but it would be better to avoid this.

**Edit 2**: I tried also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289278/is-it-possible-to-check-the-syntax-of-a-python-script-before-running-it-when-mak), using a separated python script to validate mine, but I have the same issues with undefined functions and wrong operators usage.

Comment: What is the value of `code` after the snippet above?

Comment: @John it is a `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.CompiledCode` valid object. I've read that `ScriptSource.Compile(ErrorListener)` returns `null` when it cannot compile the script, but this is not the case.

Comment: OK. I saw that and just wondered. :)

Comment: @John no problem :) I updated the question using the real types, in order to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi, I faced the same issues in the past and my conclusion is that this validates syntax, but not functionality. I think that the only way to do it is to evaluate the code, but that means to run it. So what I've done is to consider the user clever enough and consider that all script to be run are OK. Then throw an exception in case an error occurs using a MessageBox.

Comment: hi @Carles, tank you for your feedback. Unfortunately I cannot consider the user clever enough, I need to implement some kind of validation before executing the scripts in a production environment. For the moment, if this kind of validation doesn't return any error message, I try to execute the script and show to the user if there are any exceptions, but I'm still looking for better solutions :)

Comment: @mara6399 :-) I understand your point. Maybe I'm wrong but I think the only way to do it is to run the code. Keep in mind that something like v= 10 + 'a' is completely valid. This is an issue which origin is the design of the Python language itself, since it is not a strong typed language, which allows to mix and match everything. This is why many programmers hate it.